# Rails, ActiveResource, and Pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, activeresource

What's the best way to implement pagination in a REST API so that an ActiveResource client can easily navigate paginated results? There have been some proposals, for example [here](http://rubyroyd.com/2009/02/12/activeresource-pagination) and [here](http://bashmynonsense.blogspot.com/2008/05/pagination-with-activeresource.html), but being new to ActiveResource I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with kaminari and some patch to activeresource,
here is gem with example
https://github.com/Fivell/activeresource-response

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to dig into this for a project yet, but [this fork of Will_Paginate](http://github.com/larrytheliquid/will_paginate/tree/master) may be of use to you. It adds support for the `paginate` method to ActiveResource.

Answer (score 0):

We've released a gem built by us based on stuff in production in a pretty high traffic Rails app. It enables pagination transparently by adding current_page, per_page and total_entries as attributes to the root node of the serialied collection XML (and is very fast if you use LibXML or Nokogiri, which I'd strongly recommend over the default of REXML).

Here's the [link to the GitHub project for PoxPaginate](http://github.com/c42/pox_paginate).

Comment: Incidentally, Rails' serialisation implementation isn't very RESTful at all, so if you're worrying about hypermedia etc. - don't. ActiveResource is a turd and doesn't support *any* of that.